# How to compare between links

Tags: php

I'm trying to do simple ban tool system for urls that entered my website but still have problem of url compare.

I've created the following database table `badurl` with `url` I'm going to ban

```
CREATE TABLE `badurl`(
`id` int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`url` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id` (`id`))
```

Now let say I've stored the following url `www.no_good_site.com`
and someone posted `http://www.no_good_site.com` however it is the same but it won't ban it.

```
$user = "http://www.no_good_site.com" // visitor post this

// i'm gonna do compare by the stored banned urls
// I've stored this one www.no_good_site.com

$qry="select * from badurls where url='$user'";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die($qry);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)=='0'){

echo "Good";

}else{

while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "Bad";

}}
```

So is there any idea I can set both (posted and stored url) without `www.` `http://` end slash `/` then compare it. [`no_good_site.com`]

Because it failed as they might enter with many possibilities and my way needs both to be exactly the same.

```
no_good_site.com
no_good_site.com/
www.no_good_site.com/
http://no_good_site.com
http://no_good_site.com/
http://www.no_good_site.com
http://www.no_good_site.com/
```

Comment: did you try strpos to check if that string exists in other string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove http://, www. and end '/' before query:

```
$user = "http://www.no_good_site.com/";  // visitor post this
$user = rtrim(str_ireplace(array('http://', 'www.'), '', $user), '/');
```

Answer (score 2):

make all URL in similar format before comparing..

```
no_good_site.com => www.no_good_site.com
no_good_site.com/ = > www.no_good_site.com
www.no_good_site.com/ => www.no_good_site.com
http://no_good_site.com => www.no_good_site.com
http://no_good_site.com/ => www.no_good_site.com
http://www.no_good_site.com => www.no_good_site.com
http://www.no_good_site.com/ => www.no_good_site.com

<?php
    function formatURL($url) {

        //an array of strings I wish to remove
        $remove = array(
                        "http://",
                        "www.",
                        "index.html",
                        "index.php"
                        );

        //loop through array
        foreach($remove as $value) {
            //replace array values with nothing
            $url = str_ireplace($value, '', $url);
        }

        //if the url ends in a / then trim it off
        $url = rtrim($url,'/');

        return $url;

    }
?>
```

Comment: @thanks this is also working perfect and will take it as case study as it might helps me a lot with other applications. ~ thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

One easy thing would be, if you will extract the domain name from the URL entered and then search for it in the DB, not the complete URL.

You can easily get the domain name from the `$_SERVER` variable as ''SERVER_NAME''.

Comment: @Nice but won't help in this case, what if someone post link on 'hotfile' with copyrighted file, then by that way i'm gonna ban the whole hotfile links. But it can be applied in many other ways thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this?

```
$qry="select * from badurls where url LIKE '%$user%'";
```

domains can come in forms with protocols as prefixes **(http,ssl)**, along
with queries **(?blah=boo)**

Comment: Congratulations, you embedded a user-provided value into your SQL and now you are hacked.